# Where is Kweh in new game+?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

I'm doing a New Game+ in Assassin's Creed: Origins (PC, via Steam, all DLC). I just finished the "[A Gift from the Gods](https://assassinscreed.fandom.com/wiki/A_Gift_from_the_Gods)" quest and got 2 out of the 3 quest rewards -- the Ultima Blade and the Ziedrich. But I didn't get Kweh. I went outside and looked around and didn't see any chocobos hanging around the pyramid, so I'm wondering what's going on. Is it because I already have Kweh as a mount from my first play-through? I ended up with two copies of the sword and shield rewards, so I was expecting to get a second Chocobo. Or is he hanging around somewhere and I've just not found him?

Comment: Not sure, but it seems that you can't get the Chocobo again in ng+. Every GftG mission reward is unlocked at the same time, and since you are missing one probably this works as intended. You keep your mounts when starting ng+, so the game "knows" you already have it, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, but I kept my weaponry and armaments and well, but got duplicates for the quest rewards. Similarly the mainline quest where you fight as Sekhment's Champion -- I got a second copy of the kit there too. Perhaps mounts are excluded from this, though.